# Using Nlog messageGeneratorFunc and structured logging

Tags: c#, nlog

Using Log.Info for writing out structured logging is cool:

```
Log.Info("The record {id} has firstname {firstname} and lastname {lastname}",
    record.Id, record.FirstName, record.LastName)
```

I use the Debug methods too a lot.  Before I use to wrap them in `Log.IsDebugEnabled` but started using the messageGeneratorFunc variants:

```
Log.Debug(() => string.Format("The record {0} has firstname {1} and lastname {2}",
    record.Id, record.FirstName, record.LastName);
```

I'm wondering how to use structured logging with the messageGeneratorFunc?

```
Log.Debug(() => Log.Debug("The record {id} has firstname {firstname} and lastname {lastname}",
    record.Id, record.FirstName, record.LastName
```

Looks odd... `Log.Debug Log.Debug` but of course works... the internal check for IsDebugEnabled happens twice... is there a proper alternative or is that whats supposed to look like?

Answer (score 1):

The messageGeneratorFunc-delegate is for specialized serialization of heavy/large objects. NLog will not invoke the delegate when LogLevel is not enabled.

It does not make sense to use the messageGeneratorFunc-delegate for handling simple message templates. It will actually just hurt performance, because it always needs to do delegate capture, even if the LogLevel is not enabled.

This is much cheaper and faster:

```
Log.Debug("The record {0} has firstname {1} and lastname {2}",
    record.Id, record.FirstName, record.LastName);

Log.Debug("The record {id} has firstname {firstname} and lastname {lastname}",
    record.Id, record.FirstName, record.LastName);
```

Than doing this (de-optimization):

```
Log.Debug(() => string.Format("The record {0} has firstname {1} and lastname {2}",
    record.Id, record.FirstName, record.LastName);
```

See also NLog Tutorial: [Logger should handle string formatting](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial#2-logger-should-handle-string-formatting)

Comment: I guess the boxing of `int id` property on the record object is pretty minimal, possibly even catching one of the generic overloads? I hadn't considered the delegate capture issue.

Comment: NLog Logger-class actually have special generic-methods so ensure that boxing and allocations of params-array doesn't occur (Unless using more than 3 parameters)